# Call a sub after this one has finished

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform looping through a range with 2 settings; `manual` and `automatic`.

When I have an option button on my form set to `manual`, and click a `next` command button, I check the next cell in the range, change the contents of the form accordingly, then wait for the next button press.

However if I find the option button is set to `automatic` then instead of finishing up my code and waiting for the next button press, I have to call the next button press programmatically. That means that the previous subs each calling the next code slowly build up in the call stack, and I worry this will have some memory implications if I'm looping over a large range.
In code:

```
Private Sub nextItem()
Dim willShow As Boolean
returnResults 'return details from the form to the sheet
clearMemory 'clear out previous items on form
itemNo = itemNo + 1 'iterate over the range
SetupParts 'place new items on form
'do what next
Select Case displaySetting 'this variable holds the result from my option button in a custom enum "dispMode"
    Case dispMode.Manual 'always show form
        willShow = True
    Case dispMode.SemiAutomatic 'show form based on condition
        willShow = (Data.Count = 0) 'if SetupParts returns no data, display form, otherwise keep hidden
    Case dispMode.Automatic 'don't show form
        willShow = False
End Select 'there are actually a few more options here, but I've simplified
If willShow = False Then
    If Me.Visible = True Then 'if needs to hide, and currently visible, then hide the form
        Me.Hide
        nextItem 'this is the problem, I call this code again, so the call stack grows
    Else
     'form is already hidden, do nothing
    End If
ElseIf Me.Visible = False Then 'willShow must be True
    Me.Show 'then wait for button click
End If
End Sub

Private Sub commandBtnNext_Click()
    nextItem
End Sub
```

To avoid this problem, is there any way of getting `nextItem` to run immediately after the previous call of `nextItem` has run; ie. to tell a sub to run immediately after this one has finished (without introducing time delays). Or maybe this isn't an issue; if so, please explain why.

#### UPDATE

There is also a `SemiAutomatic` check to see which mode to use based on the contents of the userform. This is fine when calling recursively, but I can't see how to incorporate it into a looping approach.

Comment: why don't you just use a loop instead of a  recursive procedure call? Before the loop check if it is *automatic* or *manual* mode to determine the end of the loop.

Comment: @peh I'm feeling very slow at the moment and can't see quite how I'd construct that. I think what's got me is an extra check in my code; see update

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying to accomplish.  Specifically the interaction between the UserForm and the spreadsheet.  Can you include a picture for reference or some other means to clarify?  For what it's worth, you should be able to do this in a loop instead of recursively which eliminates the stack issue.

Comment: change the sub so that it loops through all the items (change sub name to reflect its purpose) `sub processItems() ... for each item in items ... next item ... end sub` ... this would be the automatic part (and it would not recurse). then add a test inside the loop that would pause for input if the setting was "manual"   ... the _commandBtnNext_Click_ would only set a flag. the main sub would check the flag and act accordingly